# Classification problem. I have issues with overfitting/leakage, i.e. sensitivity in training is 1.0. How do I fix this?

Tags: r, classification, boosting, overfitting

I have a consumer dataset (size: 10200x180), I am using this to develop a training model to predict consumers who would provide a referral. I have done the following to set the model.

Cleaning:
I have cleaned the dataset using [findCorrelation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/caret/versions/6.0-86/topics/findCorrelation) to reduce pair-wise correlation and [nearzerovar](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/caret/versions/6.0-86/topics/nearZeroVar) to reduce zero variance predictors in the dataset.

Model details:

- Split that data by 80-20.
- 10-fold cross validation.
- [Upsampled](https://rdrr.io/cran/caret/man/downSample.html) the training data since the classes were imbalanced.
- Even though I upsampled, i used [scale_pos_weight](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/291296) to weight the unbalanced sample so that the balance accuracy improved. Without the weight the model predicted one class by 100% and the other by 0%, with scale_pos_weight that changed.

XGB model with the following specification:

```
fitControl <- trainControl(
  method = "repeatedcv",
  number = 10,
  repeats = 1,
  classProbs = T,
  summaryFunction = twoClassSummary,
  search = "random"
)

xgbGrid<-expand.grid(nrounds = c(300,500),
                     max_depth = c(20,30,40,50),
                     eta = c(0.001),
                     gamma = 0,
                     colsample_bytree = c(.5,.7,.8,.9,1),
                     min_child_weight = c(2,4,10,100),
                     subsample=c(.7, .8, .9, 1)
)

mod <- train(Class ~ .,data=training_data, #training data is already subsetted by data_type
             method = "xgbTree",
             trControl = fitControl,
             verbose = T,
             tuneGrid = xgbGrid,
             metric = "ROC",
             scale_pos_weight=weight)
print(Sys.time() - t0)
```

The following are the results for my training and the testing model.

The best hyper parameters:

> nrounds = 488, max_depth=50, eta=0.001, gamma=0,
> colsample_bytree=0.5,min_child_weight=2, subsample=1

Training model:

- Balanced Accuracy = 0.94
- Sensitivity = 1
- Specificity = 0.89

Testing Model:

- Balanced Accuracy = 0.64
- Sensitivity = 0.47
- List item

Specificity = 0.81

Detailed results in the pictures:[training model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tG1yn.png) and [testing model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WCiKt.png)

**The training model is clearly overfit, what more should i try to do to fix the overfitting?**

Comment: (1) Please do not post an image of code/data/errors: it cannot be copied or searched (SEO), it breaks screen-readers, and it may not fit well on some mobile devices. Ref: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557 (and https://xkcd.com/2116/). Please just include the code, console output, or data (e.g., `data.frame(...)` or the output from `dput(head(x))`) directly. (2) I'm voting to migrate this to [stats.se], where you are more likely to address the theoretical aspect of the question. Good luck!

Comment: i just posted this in cross validated. should i delete this post?

Comment: Yes, I think so. It's generally frowned upon to cross post the same question. Thanks, good luck!

Comment: all preprocessing steps like removing predictors and transforming them should be performed within resampling and not prior to it to avoid data leakage and optimistic bias. Depending on your data set [block resampling](https://mlr3gallery.mlr-org.com/posts/2020-03-30-stratification-blocking/#block-resampling) might be appropriate.

Comment: Read up on proper accuracy scoring rules.  That will change all your results.  And is this really a classification problem are is it a probability prediction problem?  Your sample size is perhaps too small for split-sample methods to work, and it would be better to use 100 repeats of 10-fold cross-validation.

Comment: The obvious answer is as misuse says, you can’t use nearzerovar and findcorrelation to remove features before you split your data

Comment: But `nearzerovar` is blind to Y, so it should not hurt. No?